# How to resize ext3 partition without having physical access to the server

Tags: ubuntu, raid, partition

I have a server with 2 hard drives mounted as raid 1 using Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1              5.0G  5.0G     0 100% /
varrun                2.0G   92K  2.0G   1% /var/run
varlock               2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /var/lock
udev                  2.0G   36K  2.0G   1% /dev
devshm                2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md2              688G  2.8G  651G   1% /home
```

How can I resize the / partition without having physical access to the server ? I read this is possible using a ubuntu disc .. but this is not an option for me.

Comment: Oh I have a great memory of doing this...and then not updating the fstab before the next reboot. That was a nice 2 hour drive to the colo...taught me a lesson...all that said, be careful if you're creating additional partitions

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, by [this](http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2006/08/01/ext3-online-resizing/) article, you can expand the ext3 partition online with `sudo resize2fs /dev/md1`. This requires that the `/dev/md1` array have available unused space. If it does not, you will need to need to find someone with physical access to add an additional harddrive to the server, then add the new hard drive to the RAID array. Once the array is done rebuilding, you can then grow the ext3 partition as I described earlier. All of this can be done without rebooting the machine or taking any of the filesystems offline.